# Find out the index of a given div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Newbie jQuery question:

How do I find out what number a given div is in the DOM-tree?

```
$('div.dashboard-module').each( function() {
    var divNumber = $(this).[DON'T KNOW WHAT TO WRITE HERE];
});

alert('This div is number ' + divNumber );
```

Hope it makes sense! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know the index of the element you are currently iterating you can use the first argument of the callback function:

```
$('div.dashboard-module').each(function (index) {
    var divNumber = index;
});
```

More info:

- [each (callback)](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each#callback)

Answer (score 3):

What are you looking for the number relative to?

If its the document, then you need

```
$('div.dashboard-module').each(function(){
    var divNumber = $(document).index($(this));
});
```

If its relative to the parent, then you need

```
$('div.dashboard-module').each(function(){
    var divNumber = $($(this).parent()).index($(this));
});
```

etc.

Comment if you've got any questions

Answer (score 1):

```
var divNumber = $('div.dashboard-module');
alert("This div is number " + (divNumber.length-1) + ". " + $(divNumber[divNumber.length-1]).html() );
```